# AttributeError: Trying to access an object's attribute in a 2D list in python

Tags: python, list, recursion, indexing, attributes

I'm having trouble with accessing objects inside my 2D list in Python. Basically what I'm doing is that I have a 2D list called `recueil` (french for collection) that stores `Reflection` objects. The `Reflection` class has a `valeur`(=value) and an `indice`(=index) attribute, were the value is what I get when I apply the `ref` function (don't have it currently set up) to the reflection with a lower index (the first row of Reflections have one index, and the nth row of Reflections have n indexes, which explains the `indice[]`).

```
def main():
    a = [1, 3, 5]
    b = [2, 4, 6]
    n = 3

    recueil = [[Reflection([None],0) for colonne in range(N(ligne))] for ligne in range(n)]

    recueil[0][0].valeur = b[0] - a[0]
    recueil[0][1].valeur = b[1] - a[1]
    recueil[0][2].valeur = b[2] - a[2]

    for i in range(n):
        print(recueil[0][i].valeur)
        print(recueil[0][i].indice)

    init_indices(recueil, n)
    remplir_indices(recueil, n)


def N(n):
    return 3 * (2 ** n)

def init_indices(recueil,n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(N(i)):
            recueil[i][j] = [0] * (i+1)

class Reflection(object):
    indice = [0]
    valeur = 0
    def __init__(self, indice, valeur):
        self.indice = indice
        self.valeur = valeur
```

The problem I'm having is that in `remplir_indices`(=fill_indexes), I'm trying to make it so the initial sets have the indexes from 1 to n (so `recueil[0][0].indice` = 1, ..., `recueil[0][n-1].indice` = n) but it's treating `recueil[][]` as a list instead of the object stored in it. Any ideas as to what my error  is?

```
def remplir_indices(recueil, n):
    for i in range(n):
        if i == 0:
            for j in range(n):
                recueil[i][j].indice[0] = j
    else:
        return 0
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an indentation issue:

```
def remplir_indices(recueil, n):
    for i in range(n):
        if i == 0:
            for j in range(n):
                recueil[i][j].index[0] = j
                # recueil[i][j].indice[0] = j
        return 0
```

Comment: Fixed the indentation but that wasn't the problem it seems, still gives me the ''List' object has no attribute 'indice''

Comment: I edited the code, try again with the index method please.